# Swap operation with the Heisenberg Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, spin-models

According to REF 1 equation 3, a SWAP operation can be achieved via the Heisenberg Hamiltonian for spins $H=J(t)\mathbf{S}_1\mathbf{S_2}$

$U^{1/2}_{SWAP}=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{8}}\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{S}_1\mathbf{S}_2\right)$

where $\int_0^td\tau J(\tau)=\pi/2$

I wrote out the expression of $U^{1/2}_{SWAP}$ and it indeed results into the matrix
$U^{1/2}_{SWAP} =\left(\begin{array}{cccc}{1} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {\frac{1}{2}(1+i)} & {\frac{1}{2}(1-i)} & {0} \\ {0} & {\frac{1}{2}(1-i)} & {\frac{1}{2}(1+i)} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right)$

The physical interpretation of the term $\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{S}_1\mathbf{S}_2\right)$  is by  coupling two electron spins in quantum dots via a tunnel coupling $t_0(t)$, $J=4t_0(t)^2/U$,
where $U$ is the coulomb interaction between the electrons, for a time such that the SWAP operation is achieved and then turning off the coupling.

But how do I interpret the prefactor $e^{-i\pi/8}$ in physical terms?

REF 1:
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9905230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefactor is there to get the global phase of the SWAP right, likely for aesthetic reasons. It bears no physical relevance. You can interpret it as shifting the *overall* energy of the system, but this again has no physical relevance, as you can define energy offsets as will.

Comment: Is this similar to the freedom of adding a phase to a quantum state like $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ since this doesn't change anything about the physics $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$. I mean without the prefactor, the matrix obviously doesn't look like the SWAP matrix and the SWAP matrix is a matrix with specific values, however physically somehow it is just a SWAP matrix with some energy shift? I dont understand this when obviously the matrix without prefactor has different values than a SWAP matrix.

Comment: Global phases are not relevant.  This becomes evindent when you work with density operators, where $U$ acts as $\rho\mapsto U\rho U^\dagger$, where phases clearly cancel out.